# How to access the function in base class when using singleton class as a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton, private

It is a header of generator class;

```
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H


class Generator
{
    public:
        Generator(int);
        ~Generator();
        int getBits();

    private:
        int bits;
};

#endif // GENERATOR_H
```

.
It is a header of proxy class which is singleton class drived from Generator;

```
#ifndef PROXY_H
#define PROXY_H
#include "Generator.h"

class Proxy: private Generator
{
    public:
        ~Proxy();
        static Proxy* getInstance(int);
        Generator * operator ->();
        int checkvalue();
    private:
        Proxy();
        Proxy(int);
        int bits;
        int counter;
        static Proxy* instance;
        Generator * rPointer;
};

#endif // GENERATORPROXY_H
```

.
This is CPP file for Proxy.

```
Proxy::Proxy(int inputbits):Generator(inputbits)
{
}

Proxy::~Proxy()
{

}
Generator * Proxy::operator ->()
{
    counter++;

    if(counter<=10)
    return rPointer;
    else
    return 0;
}

Proxy* Proxy::instance = 0;

Proxy* Proxy::getInstance(int inputbits)
{
    if(instance==0)
    {
        instance = new Proxy(inputbits);
    }

    return instance;

}
```

Question: When I make some proxy object in main function, how I can call the getBits() function in main?

This is part of main function:

```
Proxy* px = Proxy::getInstance(4);
cout << px->getBits() << endl;
```

When I tried it error happend like this: `int Generator::getBits() is inaccessible. Generator is not an accessible base of Proxy.` 
The way I can access Generator in main, I made operator like this: `Generator * Proxy::operator ->()` which is in CPP file for proxy. How can I access to the getBits() function in main function? Thank you all your help.

Comment: Why is the inheritance ```private Generator ```?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk that's the declaration of singleton class to keep the any users from accessing Generator class.

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean I cannot access function in Generator class? I want to make a limitation up to 10 access of Generator class.

Comment: I need to call the function to use operator -> in main fuction, is it possible?

Comment: Try composition. In this case its the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

The inheritance is `private` that means everything from the base `Generator` class is going into the `private` part of `Proxy` class.
If The `public` functions from `Generator` are to be visible, then You need make the inheritance `public`
-or-
create a `public` function in `Proxy` which calls the needed functions in `Generator`

**Issue 2:**

Inheritance is used when we need to use Derived classes (many times unknown classes) in a certain context. The Base class represents the abstract concept behind all the Derived classes. And it is used as a "common" concept between all the Derived classes.

In other words: Is the `Generator` an abstraction of a `Proxy` -or- is the `Proxy` a specific type of `Generator`.
If not, then I would use composition (make it a variable in `Proxy`).

**Issue 3:**

In the comments, there is also a requirement to the amount of times the `Generator` class is accessed. With inheritance, the `Generator` class has to control all the access to it.

So this is why You have a `Proxy` class. It is an extra level of indirection - it is a wrapper for Your `Generator` class, it should delegate all the calls to it.

The `Proxy` class should have all the required functions that need to be called. It is the "protector" of the `Generator` class (That's probably why `private` inheritance is used).

---

These issues are design issues, for which You have to decide, what is best.

Answer (score 0):

To use `Proxy::operator->` you have to dereference `px` first. So `(*px)->getBits()` should do the trick.

And as Eduard Rostomyan says, you should use a composite instead of inheritance, since a Proxy is **not** a Generator.

Additionally, you are not setting rPointer anywhere in your code sample and your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, code worked but when it run the code, the program was shut down.

Comment: I setup rPointer in Proxy header.

Comment: @GideokSeong: Can you also post the code where you assign the value to rPointer?

It may also be easier to replace `Generator *rPointer;` with `Generator generator;` and return `&generator` in `operator->`. That way you get rid of the inheritance in the Proxy class.